# SQL Update - Cant specify target table in select

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
#key | #value
colour | red
weather | blue
```

Now I want to update the value of the row with the key colour to be the value of the row with the key weather. So I am doing:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET value = (SELECT value FROM table_name WHERE key = "weather") 
WHERE key = "colour";
```

But this update gives me following error message:

> You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

How can I do that query without error?

Comment: Sorry, but why does this question get a bad reputition, when no answer is working up to now?

Comment: The solution is to use a temporary table:

    UPDATE table_name SET value = (SELECT value FROM (SELECT value FROM table_name WHERE key="weather) AS x) WHERE key="colour"

Comment: I guess you have not seen my updated answer. I have also answered the same and also referenced a very interesting article on the same!

Answer (score 1):

This may be because it may be the case that the `select` query returns more than one value for the column `value`

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET value = (SELECT max(value) FROM table_name WHERE key = "weather")
WHERE key = "colour";
```

or

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET value = (SELECT value FROM table_name WHERE key = "weather" limit 1) 
WHERE key = "colour";
```

You may try to change it like this by replacing the instance of `table_name` in the sub-query with `(SELECT * FROM table_name)`:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET table_name.A =
(
    SELECT B
    FROM (SELECT * FROM table_name) AS something
    INNER JOIN ...
)
```

Also check [How to select from an update target in MySQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/)

> You don’t want to just SELECT * FROM table in the subquery in real
>   life; I just wanted to keep the examples simple. In reality you should
>   only be selecting the columns you need in that innermost query, and
>   adding a good WHERE clause to limit the results, too.

EDIT:-

As you have already commented that but I have answered above to use the temporary table like this:-

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET value = (SELECT value FROM (SELECT value FROM table_name WHERE key="weather") AS x) 
WHERE key="colour"
```

Answer (score 0):

you might try this if your sql supports 'LIMIT'

```
UPDATE table_name SET value = (SELECT value FROM table_name WHERE key = "weather" LIMIT 1 ) WHERE key = "colour";
```

Comment: How should that help in my case?

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET colour ='red',weather =blue
WHERE column_name = some_value;
```

Comment: This won't work. I want the value attribute of the row with the key colour, to be the value attribite of the row with the key weather.

Answer (score -1):

It won't work that way. You can't have a read and a write query at the same time for the same table. With two different tables it will work.

```
UPDATE `table` SET value = (SELECT value FROM `Table_b` WHERE `other_value` = 'xy' LIMIT 1) WHERE  `key` =  'colour'
```